# React JS auto complete functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a reactJS webapp that has many different functional components, each functional component has some props and it is hard to keep track of what each functions takes in as props. Is there a way to suggest props in the compiler?

I've tried searching this issue to no avail

this is an example code

```
// creating a custom functional components
import React from "react";
import "./FadedText.scss";
export default function FadedText(props) {
  return <p className="fadedText">{props.text ?? "Faded text"}</p>;
}
```

and inside another file I want to

```
import React from "react"
import FadedText from "./FadedText"

function SomeName()=>
{
// Suggests a prop called text inside of FadedText for it to be given a value when I click 
// Ctrl+space
 return <FadedText >;
}
```

So when I import them the props names are suggested by the compiler. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code in child component

```
     const {useCallback, useEffect} = React;

     const handleKeyPress = useCallback((event) => {
        console.log(`Key pressed: ${event.key}`);
        console.log(props)
      }, []);
      
        useEffect(() => {
        // attach the event listener
        document.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyPress);
      }, [handleKeyPress]);
```

For control and space you may have to write logic like to store first key up of value and second key up of value... When both first and second is sequential to met `ctrl + space` you can trigger `console.log(props)`

Comment: Thank you kind stranger but I think you misinterpreted my questions, Chris G answer did it for me.

Comment: Actually I have used that.. But you where looking for shortcut keys right... That whyh I throw this sol. Anyway great though!